# Is it possible to make persistent full-screen camera like System camera app?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, fullscreen

I am building a custom camera app, and would like to have the camera view similar to the native camera app in iPhone. (i.e., picks videos as a non-modal view, stays in the camera view after each video taken. I found the retake and use views unnecessary). Is there any possible way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it for videos at present, but you can do it for still pictures in OS 3.1.  if you search for "takePicture" and "cameraOverlayView" you should find helpful information; you can resize the preview window to be any size you like.